# Can I use these cheap GSM module with arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I found two cheap GSM module on ebay but didn't know that I can use them with Arduino or not.
Will you help me please?

Here are the link-

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Smallest-SIM800L-GSM-Module-Micro-SIM-Board-Quad-band-Port-Onboard-Antenna-/111789339320?hash=item1a0729f2b8

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SIM900A-Development-Board-Extension-Module-GSM-GPRS-Antenna-TTL-e/281517486292?_trksid=p2045573.c100033.m2042&_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20131017132637%26meid%3D70128bc79b60410d862b64d36cc479b3%26pid%3D100033%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D4%26sd%3D281517486292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both seem to have the pin header for a serial port. So chances are that they can take standard AT commands.
I've seen many modems using additional AT commands for special functions, but they all supported also the basic AT commands.

Answer (score 1):

The SIM900A won't work in the UK, it's dual band.
The SIM800L is cheap as there is no power regulation on board. IIRC it requires 3.4V - 4.5V, min 2 amp supply. Check the data sheet to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use the sim900a and 900a mini in the uk but you will have to download firmware and flashing tools that you will find with a web search, not for the beginner though, an 800l is your best bet with a SMA Female JACK Connector to U.FL/IPX Converter Pigtail Cable F1445K so you can attach an sma antenna

cheers
Stuart